# I am writing the python script for copy the certain multiple image files (.jpg)from one folder by giving multiple input in one line to another folder

Tags: python

I have large jpeg files dataset.file name are like this 965_0000000005_0000000001_20211105153826.jpg
965_0000000005_0000000002_20211105153826.jpg
.
.

966_0000000005_0000000001_20211105153832.jpg
.
.

967_.........
.
.

so on...
I want to make the python script to copy the file by giving multiple inputs the file names according 965, 966, 988, ., .,.. and then it will copy to new folder.
I am trying to copy multiple image files from one folder to another using the following code

````
import os

import shutil

import datetime




def copyImage (num):

    data = os.walk(os.path.normcase('./'))

    flag = False

    for root, dirs, files in data: 

        for file in files:

            if (file.split('_')[0] == num and file.endswith('.jpg')):

                flag = True

                filename = os.path.join(root, file)

                try:

                    shutil.copyfile(filename, str(datetime.date.today()) + slash + file)

                except:

                    pass

    if flag == True: print('OK==>No %s has been copied.' %num)

    elif flag == False: print('NG==>No %s does not exist.' %num)

    return

 if __name__ == '__main__':
        while True:

        slash = os.path.normcase('/')



        number = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple values: ").split()))
        # print(number)
        annotationNum=[]

        for num in number:
          # print(num)
          num=str(num)

          num=eval(num)

          annotationNum.append(num)
          # print(annotationNum)
        

        if annotationNum =='q':

            break

        try:

            os.makedirs(str(datetime.date.today()))

        except:

            pass



        for num in annotationNum:

          copyImage (num)
    ```

     output is
Enter multiple values:  965 966 968 4
NG==>No 965 does not exist.
NG==>No 966 does not exist.
NG==>No 968 does not exist.
NG==>No 4 does not exist.
Enter multiple values:  q

but I want the o/p
Enter multiple values:  965 966 968 4
OK==>No 965 has been copied.
OK==>No 966 has been copied.
OK==>No 968 has been copied.
NG==>No 4 does not exist.
Enter multiple values:  q
````

Comment: You're passing integers to `copyImage`, but then you compare them to strings (in `file.split('_')[0] == num`. That's never going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this script... I made some inline comments explaining any changes that I made.  I wasnt sure what the `'q'` conditional statement was for so you might want to put that back in if it was important.

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

def copyImage (numbers, target):   # send in the full list of numbers to avoid
                                   # multiple function calls
                                   # Also send in the target directory to avoid
                                   # having to reconstruct it over and over
    unused = numbers[:]
    data = os.walk(os.path.normcase('./'))
    for root, _, files in data:
        for filename in files:
            # the next line splits the filename just as before but instead of
            # comparing it to one number, it checks if it matches any of the
            # numbers in the number list
            part = filename.split('_')[0]
            if part in numbers and filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                if part in unused:
                    unused.remove(part)
                fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                try:
                    #  Use the target directory passed as a parameter to
                    # construct the copy location
                    shutil.copyfile(fullpath, os.path.join(target, filename))
                    # output messages when they happen to avoid dealing with
                    #  flag variables
                    print(f"OK==>No {fullpath} has been copied.")
                except:
                    print(f"NG==>No {part} failed to copy")
    for number in unused:
        print(f"NG==>No {number} does not exist")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    target = str(datetime.date.today())  # construct the output target directory
    os.makedirs(target)                 # create the target directiory
    numbers = input("Enter multiple values: ").split()  # get input values and
                                                        # split them into a
                                                        # list but leave them
                                                        # as strings since
    numbers = [i.strip() for i in numbers if i]
    copyImage(numbers, target)  # call function with the string list and
                                # the target directory
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Python script worked.
The 'q' conditional statement is not necessary.

Comment: I have question about output of above program
 Enter multiple values:  967 800 78
OK==>./gray_images/967_0000000005_0000000001_20211105153901.jpg has been copied.
OK==>./gray_images/967_0000000005_0000000002_20211105153901.jpg has been copied.
OK==>./gray_images/967_0000000005_0000000003_20211105153901.jpg has been copied.  
it doesnt shows the out put for  800 and  78
NG==>./gray_images/800_0000000005_0000000003_20211105153901.jpg doesn not copy.
NG==>./gray_images/78_0000000005_0000000003_20211105153901.jpg doesn not copy.

Comment: Thank you so much detailed explanation.
I am sorry, I didnt mention clearly that file 800 and 78  are not in the folder then want output as file does not exit.
Since I will use this script for large dataset then seeing output it will cleared that file 800 and 78 are doesnt exit in the folder.

Comment: It works. Thank you once again for making changes in the program. Program is easy and understandable for beginners like me.

Comment: I want to ask the question what I have to do, if I want to  the output  like below.
enter the values: 965~1015
output
oK==>965_0000000005_0000000001_20211105153901.jpg
.
.
.
Ok==>1015_0000000005_0000000003_20211105153901.jpg has been copied.

Comment: @Yuna  I would love to help you out with that.  Please open a new StackOverflow question, copy and paste the current code you are using, even if it is the same as above, and ask include the description like you did in your comment.  Then if you want you can post a link here to the question or I will look at your profile to see if you have posted every once in a while

Comment: I got it. I have made new question. Could please help me out. Here is the new question link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625406/i-am-writing-the-python-script-for-copy-the-image-files-jpgfrom-one-folder-to>

Comment: @Yuna  I replied to your question with an ideal means of doing what you ask.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple way to do that!

First, to quit the while loop with **'q'** we have to read users' inputs as **str**.

Next, by importing **glob** you can insert the names of the whole files (.jpg) to a **list**

Then, inside **copyImage** function, you need to change this to the folder name that you want to read your images from **THE_NAME_OF_THE_FOLDER_TO_COPY_FROM**

Now, using the power of **List Comprehension** we can do it by one line of code by looping in **images** and only do the copy when we find our intended **num**

Let me know if you need more explanation?

```
import shutil
import glob
import datetime
import os

def copyImage(num):
    images = glob.glob("THE_NAME_OF_THE_FOLDER_TO_COPY_FROM/*.jpg")
    # print(images)
    [shutil.copy(img, str(datetime.date.today())) for img in images if img.split('/')[1].split('_')[0] == str(num)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        numbers = list(map(str, input("Enter multiple values: ").split()))
        # print(numbers)

        if 'q' in numbers:
            print("Exit")
            break

        nums = [eval(number) for number in numbers]
        # print(num)

        try:
            os.makedirs(str(datetime.date.today()))
        except:
            pass    

        for n in nums:
            copyImage(n)
```

Comment: Ok, could you show me the result of `print(images)`? it is being commented now in the above code, just remove the comment!

Comment: @Yuna

Sorry, I think I got it. since our images name will have sth like `FOLDER_NAME/IMAGE_NAME.png` so we have first to `split` by `/` and then `split` again by `_` . Please give it a try again since I've edited the code!